# Trying to merge two JSONobjects in android

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

I am trying to merge two json objects in android using the following piece of code:

```
Iterator<?> i1 = store_ordinary_data.keys();
Iterator<?> i2 = store_premium_data.keys();
while(i1.hasNext()) {
    tmp_key = (String) i1.next();
    mergedObj.put(tmp_key, store_ordinary_data.get(tmp_key));
}
while(i2.hasNext()) {
    tmp_key = (String) i2.next();
    mergedObj.put(tmp_key, store_premium_data.get(tmp_key));
```

The resulting merged JSON should contain 5 pieces of data.But one of the piece of data is missing.What am i doing wrong in the above piece of code?

EDIT the JSON :

```
{
category: [2]
0:  "Hospital"
1:  "Hotel"
-
store_ordinary_data: {
Hospital: [2]
0:  {
store_name: "KIMS Hospital"
store_image: "index.jpg"
store_address: "near mecdical college"
store_phone: "74126842365"
store_description: "fdsfdsfdff fdsf dsf dsf "
store_url: "dfffsfsdfsfs"
store_latitude: "8.505786"
store_longitude: "76.960194"
store_fb_url: "https://www.facebook.com/iglooappschool"
store_priority: "NO"
store_distance: "0.037973763177421405"
store_gallery: [1]
0:  "index.jpg"
-
}-
1:  {
store_name: "SP Fort Hospital"
store_image: "index1.jpg"
store_address: "fdsfdsfds s sfds d f"
store_phone: "343423423423"
store_description: "fdsffdsf dsfdfdfdf dsf d dd"
store_url: "fdffdsfsffsff"
store_latitude: "8.484709"
store_longitude: "76.941474"
store_fb_url: "https://www.facebook.com/iglooappschool"
store_priority: "NO"
store_distance: "3.0969432359767195"
store_gallery: [2]
0:  "index1.jpg"
1:  "index3.jpg"
-
}-
-
Hotel: [1]
0:  {
store_name: "Malus"
store_image: "index3.jpg"
store_address: "Kazhakoottam"
store_phone: "124464567"
store_description: "gfdgdfgdfg d sfsgs sdfdsfdf "
store_url: "gdgdgdgdgdgddgd"
store_latitude: "8.571409"
store_longitude: "76.864965"
store_fb_url: "https://www.facebook.com/iglooappschool"
store_priority: "NO"
store_distance: "12.790990805465954"
store_gallery: [1]
0:  "index3.jpg"
-
}-
-
}-
store_premium_data: {
Hotel: [2]
0:  {
store_name: "Vishnu Restarunt"
store_image: "index.jpg"
store_address: "kattakada"
store_phone: ""
store_description: ""
store_url: ""
store_latitude: "8.489065"
store_longitude: "76.957282"
store_fb_url: "https://www.facebook.com/iglooappschool"
store_priority: "YES"
store_distance: "1.8514660234169065"
store_gallery: [1]
0:  "index3.jpg"
-
}-
1:  {
store_name: "AZAD"
store_image: "index2.jpg"
store_address: "East fort"
store_phone: "3542355452"
store_description: "sfsdfsfv dfzfdsfdsfg dsfdssdf"
store_url: "fdsfdsfdsfsdf"
store_latitude: "8.486363"
store_longitude: "76.951697"
store_fb_url: "https://www.facebook.com/iglooappschool"
store_priority: "YES"
store_distance: "2.322390609287792"
store_gallery: [1]
0:  "index2.jpg"
-
}-
-
}-
}
```

The missing piece is the Hotel in the first JSON.The problem i think is that when the first while runs,the missing piece is present.But when the second while runs,since the second json also contains the 'Hotel' key the older hotel seems to have been overwritten.How do i make it an adding operation instead of an overwriting one

EDIT:

I modified the code as follows and now getting JSON Exception:

```
JSONObject mergedObj = new JSONObject();
                    Iterator<?> i1 = store_ordinary_data.keys();
                    Iterator<?> i2 = store_premium_data.keys();
                    while(i1.hasNext()) {
                        tmp_key = (String) i1.next();
                        mergedObj.put(tmp_key, store_ordinary_data.get(tmp_key));
                    }
                    while(i2.hasNext()) {
                        tmp_key = (String) i2.next();
                        if(mergedObj.has(tmp_key)){
                            JSONArray jsonexsarr=mergedObj.getJSONArray(tmp_key);
                            jsonexsarr.put(store_premium_data.get(tmp_key));
                            mergedObj.put(tmp_key,jsonexsarr);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        mergedObj.put(tmp_key, store_premium_data.get(tmp_key));
                        }

                    }
```

The problem in the code is that when the two hotels from the second json are added , they are added a single array within the first array.I want the two hotels to  be added as objects in the first array.

Comment: what piece is missing.. what do the two jsonObjects look like

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, there might be two duplicate keys and one value got overwritten in the second loop.

Comment: Yes exactly.But i want the values in the second json to be concatentated with values in the first json, not  overwritten.I managed to merge the two json (see edit) , but the problem is that , the second set of values were added as a sub array , i want them to be objects in the first array.